# How to append some string combined with the pattern at the end of line with the pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to append .com at the end of line for every line matching the pattern in /etc/hosts file.

Sample file content:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
1.2.3.4 hostname1 hostname1.xyz hostname1.xyz.  
1.2.3.5 hostname2 hostname2.xyz hostname2.xyz.  
1.2.3.6 hostname3 hostname3.xyz hostname3.xyz.
```

I want it to be like below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.com
1.2.3.4 hostname1 hostname1.xyz hostname1.xyz. hostname1.xyz.com  
1.2.3.5 hostname2 hostname2.xyz hostname2.xyz. hostname2.xyz.com  
1.2.3.6 hostname3 hostname3.xyz hostname3.xyz. hostname3.xyz.com
```

Any `sed` or `awk` command to achieve this effect?

Comment: So all your lines are in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: yes, they are in /etc/hosts file only.

Comment: So `awk '$0 = $0 " " $NF "com"' <file` should do the trick.

Comment: @cuonglm This works!! Thanks. Just for the sake of /etc/hosts consistency which also has "127.0.0.1   localhost" entry on first line, this added just "com" at the end of line. It should have been nice if it was localhost.com not localhostcom. Note: mind the DOT here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$0 = $0 " " $NF ($NF ~ /\.$/ ? "" : ".") "com"' <file
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.com
1.2.3.4 hostname1 hostname1.xyz hostname1.xyz. hostname1.xyz.com
1.2.3.5 hostname2 hostname2.xyz hostname2.xyz. hostname2.xyz.com
1.2.3.6 hostname3 hostname3.xyz hostname3.xyz. hostname3.xyz.com
```

Comment: Do we need to write this output to some temp file and then overwrite original file? I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019617/how-to-write-finding-output-to-same-file-using-awk-command

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Perl, does inplace editing

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\s\S+?)(\.?)\s*$/$1$2$1.com\n/' /etc/hosts
```

- `\s` match a white-space character
- `\S+?` non-greedy match 1 or more non-white-space characters
- `\.?` greedy match 0 or 1 times the . character (to take care of possible extra . at end of line)
- `\s*$` greedy match any white-space characters at end of line
- `$1$2` retain the last column, excluding end of line white-space characters
- `$1.com\n` add .com and newline character

change `-i` to `-i.bkp` to have a backup (/etc/hosts.bkp) of original file

Note: this regular expression won't work with `sed` as BRE/ERE doesn't support non-greedy matching

Comment: I moved to perl from awk as escaping the quotes, double quotes, $ etc. was giving me hard time. I am trying to execute this perl command using ssh on remote machine from a python program. What should be the way to escape all needed ones?

Comment: what's your current line of code? and you could as well write this code in python to save all the trouble of calling external command

Comment: program pseudo code goes like:

<some python code>
funcSshRemote(perl_cmd, remote_host)
<some python code>